# Given a set of 12 integers, how to recursively generate all possible 4 groups of 3? C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion

For example given the set {1,2,...,11,12},
one possible 4 groups of 3 is

(12, 1, 7)
(3, 6, 9)
(4, 11, 2)
(10, 8, 5)

Comment: hint: combination without repetition should be a good starting point.

Comment: One more hint: generate all possible groups of 12 and split them into 4 parts from first element.

Comment: I think this question may be been put on hold a bit too quickly (for the stated reason). The problem is more subtle than the two "solutions" given above suggest: if permutations of the four groups are not allowed - i.e. if there should be only one of (abc)(def)(ghi)(jkl) and (def)(abc)(ghi)(jkl), then you need to work quite a bit harder to generate the unique groups. It can be done but it's not a one-liner. Having said that, it sounds like homework, and I don't see any effort by OP to attempt a solution. That's a better reason to put on hold...

Comment: This sounds like apriori algorithm

Answer (score 1):

Think how the factorial calculation works - if you wanted all the possible permutations, you'd count `n!` because that's the number of ways to pick the first element, multiplied by the number of ways to pick the second afterwards, and so on. That should be fairly easy to implement with loop that actually goes over all possibilities and recursively builds all these permutations.

After (or during) picking a permutation for all possible elements in a row, you just need to eliminate the redundant possibilities - the ones where one or more of the triplets is a simple shuffle of the other, and the ones where all the triplets are identical but the 4 groups a ordered differently.

A simple way to achieve that is to sort each group internally (i.e. `(12 2 1) (5 4 2) .. --> (1 2 12) (2 4 5) ..`), and sort again based on the first element of each group, and then go over the list of permutations and eliminate consecutive identical elements